# Issues trying to test Knowledge Base Articles

Tags: unit-test, knowledge

I have some code that queries KnowledgeArticleVersions and I'm trying to test it.  In order to do so, I first need to add articles...

```
@isTest
public class ORC_TestUtils {

    public static void addPublishedArticle(){
            Issue__kav article= new Issue__kav(
            Title = generateRandomString(),
            UrlName = generateRandomString()
            );
            insert article;
            //using object because all objects have the same properties
            KnowledgeArticleVersion a = [SELECT KnowledgeArticleId FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion WHERE Id = :(Id) article.get('id')];
            KbManagement.PublishingService.publishArticle(a.KnowledgeArticleId, true);

    }
}
```

This seems to work fine when I test it in my sandbox, but when I try to validate in production, it fails with this message:

> System.NoAccessException: Insufficient Privileges: You do not have the
>   level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested.
>   Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access
>   is necessary.

I've tried using `System.runAs()` with a sys admin user but I get the same results... Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Does your running user have the knowledge feature active?

Comment: @Girbot is that a specific setting in my user? as Opposed to the profile?

Comment: yes it's a feature licence on the user record  not profile. Sys admins don't have it by default

Comment: @Girbot Looks like that was it.  Want to submit an official answer?

Comment: Done, glad that sorted it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to be able to create and edit a Knowledge Article the running user needs the "Knowledge User" checkbox ticked on the user record. This is a feature licence that is not controlled currently within a profile and sys admin do not get the permission by default.

[image]

An explanation of the permissions required can be found at the link below. Note any user can now view Articles but the feature licence is required in order to create and/or edit:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=knowledge_setup_assign_users.htm&language=en_US